# Variable column number pl/sql cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have a function that returns a Select clause with a variable number of columns (from 2 to 31). Then, I need to do inserts into a table using the first + each of the other columns. For example, if my Select returns: ('A', '1', '2', '3') I need to insert ('A','1'), ('A','2') and ('A','3') into a given table. The problem is that I can't know how many columns I'll have in the original Select clause.

I tried to use the Select clause to open a cursor but, is there any way I can know how many columns the cursor has and, then, fetch them separately? Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Ander.

Comment: Can we see the functions involved?

Answer (score 0):

You are in need of [dbms_sql.describe_columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#i997238)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I finally managed to solve it. As Sanders says, using dbms_sql, I open a cursor, parse it, get the column number with describe_columns, and in a loop, define their formats (luckily for me, all of them are varchar2(6)).

Finally, I use dbms_sql.column_value to get each column's value while I fetch all the rows.